# TKinterで作成したGUIアプリで日本語入力できない

Tags: python, python3, tkinter

現在TKinterでGUIアプリを作成しています。
コード欄のenryウィジェットに日本語を入力させたいですが入力できません。（何か入力しても何も表示されません）
どのようにすればいいか教えていただきたいです。

Ubuntuの$LANGはja_JP.UTF8に設定しましたが、変わらず何も入力できません。

お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

実行環境

- Python 3.9.8, anaconda
- TKinter 8.6
- wsl, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

以下コード

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Entry widget")
root.geometry("300x60")

frame = tk.Frame(root, pady=20, padx=5)
entry = tk.Entry(frame)

frame.pack()
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 実行環境の説明に「Win10 Pro」「Ubuntu20.04LTS」とあるのは、そのどちらでも同じ現象が起きている、という意味でしょうか？ また、Pythonの実行環境は何でしょうか？

Comment: 以下の環境では日本語入力できました。 ご参考まで。Windows11、Python 3.9.12（Anaconda）

Comment: Win10 Proではできましたが,　Ubuntu環境ではできませんでした。できれどちらの環境でもできるようにしたいです。

Comment: pythonの実行環境はWin10, Ubuntuともにanacondaです。

Comment: 「日本語を入力させたいですが入力できません。」というのはどういう状況でしょうか？何も表示されないのでしょうか？文字化けするのでしょうか？ubuntuの日本語入力設定はされていますか？

Comment: 何か入力しても何も表示されなく、文字通り入力できない状態です。
Ubuntuの$LANGはja_JP.UTF8に設定しまいたが、変わらず何も入力できません。